# Is it dangerous to access wordpress tables directly?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm coding an iOS app that will share information with a wordpress site.
I had originally created a separate database with a custom data entry page in php but the client would like data entry to be done via wordpress forms for both user and admin.
So the easiest way to modify my code is just to look at the table wordpress creates and read from it directly. Is this common practice or considered a no-no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hosted on Wordpress.com, you can use the REST API documented here:

http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Otherwise, your main alternative is a third-party REST API plugin, which you could use to give your iOS app access via HTTP to whatever data and CRUD operations you choose. Here are links to a few of those:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

http://thermal-api.com/

http://jetpack.me/support/json-api/

What you're describing is both a common practice and considered a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

Just install a JSON/XML plugin in your Wordpress system and get the data from there. Best option you got in my opinion.. A separate database needs to be synchronized with the wordpress database, which is a pain in the ass..